# Restarting game, button always causes crash

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm working on my first android application a simple yahtzee game. Currently I'm trying to restart my game by clicking a play again button. I've switched views (gameover.xml) and have the onclick in the xml point to a playagain function.

I've kind of got two questions regarding this, first would be that even with an empty method the button causes the application to crash. I'm not exactly sure why. The second is what would be the best method for restarting my game? I was thinking that restarting the activity would be the easiest way but I'm open to other suggestions. Below is the xml code for my play again button:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/playbutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Play Again"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="playagain"
>
</Button>
```

I've tried a couple of different methods for restarting my game but haven't been able to test if they work because my app keeps crashing as soon as the button is pressed. In case I've got something setup incorrectly here's the empty playagain function:

```
private void playagain(){
}
```

I appreciate the help. This site has provided lots of answers for me throughout the development process.

Comment: Can you get a logcat of the error your seeing? You should only ask one question per page and without any code it would be difficult to help determine how to restart the game. Instead of actually starting your game in onCreate i would have a method that starts it so that i could call it again when i need to start over.

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't think of that. Here's my logcat: http://pastesite.com/22119

Answer (score 1):

`playagain()` needs to take a `View` as a parameter, and it needs to be a `public` method:

```
 public void playagain(View v) {
    // something
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it! I managed to get my app to restart also.